# How to capture mouse/trackpad mode in Splashtop client?

Tags: remote-desktop, splashtop

I am using [Splashtop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splashtop) which is a remote desktop software which allows me to connect and control the computer using Android.

In the Android client I can capture my mouse so that I can use the scroll wheel or hover over icons etc. But I cannot capture the mouse in the Linux client.

How to capture mouse/trackpad mode in Splashtop client on Linux?

Comment: I'm already beginning to see some terrible down sides to splashtop that make it completely useless. 1) If the Linux client can not capture mouse that totally kills it. 2) I can not access the streamer outside of my home network without paying monthly (terrible, disgusting, useless) //// streaming onto my android tablet just works so amazingly it all has me very disappointed.

Comment: What is "splashtop"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one solution:

1. Install Wine (windows emulator)
2. Go get the splashtop personnel .exe
3. Install and run in Wine

Pros: It works! Yay!

cons: It aint Linux so might be slower